# AVX segmentation fault on linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++, simd, avx

I am trying to run this code and it says segmentation fault when I run it. It compiles good. Here is the code. (It works fine on windows).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<immintrin.h>

const int size = 1000000;

std::vector<float>A(size);
std::vector<float>B(size);
std::vector<float>C(size);

void bar(int i){
    const float a = 2.0f;
    __m256 _a = _mm256_broadcast_ss(&a);
    __m256 _A = _mm256_load_ps(&A[0] + i*8);
    __m256 _B = _mm256_load_ps(&B[0] + i*8);
    __m256 _C = _mm256_add_ps(_B, _mm256_mul_ps(_a,_A));
    _mm256_store_ps(&C[0] + i*8, _C);
}


int main(){
    std::fill(A.begin(), A.end(), 1.0f);
    std::fill(B.begin(), B.end(), 2.0f);
    bar(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling: `g++ -mavx t2.cpp -o t2`

It's exiting when it hit the first AVX instruction.
I just want someone to review my code.

Here is gdb back trace

```
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400aea in bar(int) ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-78.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400aea in bar(int) ()
#1  0x0000000000400b95 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: "compile good" does not mean "is a useable program". You need to explain WHERE this code crashes. we're not going to try and GUESS where the fault is.

Comment: Sure. It is crashing when it hit the first AVX instruction

Comment: For starters, it looks like you are referencing `&A[0] + i*8` when i isn't your loop variable. Also, I'd make sure `loop` is divisible by 8, and do `j+=8` as your loop increment and set your address to `A[j]`. Additionally, your vectors may not be aligned correctly, you should check that A[0] is aligned as AVX requires. Most modern compilers do align memory for performance reasons but I don't know what guarentees are made. That's why a lot of SSE/AVX code uses things such as `_aligned_malloc`

Comment: Even with removing the loop. It is showing the same. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @RyanP: But it is working on windows. Do you think alignment can be a problem?

Comment: MSVC chooses to use `vmovups` instead of `vmovaps`, even when a `_mm256_load_ps` intrinsic guarantees alignment at compile time.  That's why it happens to work there.  (Not because of Windows per se, e.g. clang on Windows would work just like Linux.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably an data alignment issue. _mm256_load_ps requires 256-bit (32-bytes) aligned memory. The default allocator for std::vector doesn't meet that requirement. You'll need to supply an aligned allocator or use another instruction with less stringent alignment requirement (such as _mm256_loadu_ps).

Comment: Thank you it worked! Thank you @RyanP for alternate answer! :)